# Is there a way to make a discord.js bot join a voice channel on it's own?

Tags: discord, discord.js

I'm trying to make a discord bot with discord.js and one of the things I need it to do is join a voice channel on its own, even if there is no one in the call. The only way I can find to make it join the voice channel is if someone sends a command in a text channel that tells the bot to join, I don't want this. I want the bot to join a voice channel on it's own with or without anyone being in the voice channel. If anyone knows how to do this, please guide me in the right direction of what I would have to do. Thanks

Comment: https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/VoiceChannel?scrollTo=join (v12 docs, be careful if you're still on v11)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some example to join randomVoiceChannel every 10s.

```js
client.on('ready', () => {
  let targetGuild = client.guilds.cache.get('GUILD ID')
  setTimeout(() => {
       targetGuild.channels.cache.filter(ch => ch.type === 'voice').random().join()
  }, 10000);
});
```